# Alternative to SSRS

Tags: reporting

Can anybody suggest me alternative to SSRS for building reports with complex datasource. My stored procedure returns multiple select queries and I want to use all of that tables in my report.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple way by creating a new page and rendering those tables into that page.

Comment: I need to use reports because this report must have appropriate template and must called from several application via web reference or somehow other way.

Comment: Can you split that store procedure into multiple store procedures? Then you can use ssrs normally.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not real, my stored procedure is so complicated, there is many common variables and temporary tables inside. Therefore I cannot split stored procedure into multiple or join my table results into one table.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can't utilize multiple tables in one dataset, you can use multiple datasets in SSRS that use **temporary tables**.

Create one dataset that creates your data with multiple temp tables and returns one table.

Create separate datasets that gets the data you need for your other temp tables.

Check the **Use Single Transaction when processing queries** on your **DataSources** properties so that the temp tables persist until the other datasets get their data.

I don't think Business Objects or Qlikview would work any better with your source. Not sure about any others. Otherwise you might end up having to create your own from scratch in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Like SSRS, RockDaisy is based on sql queries. The developer can use the sql editor or sql stored procedures (queries stored on database server).

RockDaisy separates the developer interface from the end user. This allows the end-user experience to be super simple (drag and drop)

The UI/UX is completely customize-able allowing customers to brand and optional embed into existing apps.